# How to decide whether a variable belongs to a linear model?

Tags: regression, modeling, model-selection, regression-coefficients, model

I have a set of inputs $x$ and noisy outputs $y$. I think that either $$y = a_0 + a_1 x$$ or $$y = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2.$$ How can I determine which model was more likely to have generated the data?

Could this be done by cross-validating ordinary least squares and lasso regression on these data, and then doing a paired hypothesis test to see which has the better median coefficient of determination?

Comment: If you mean "Given the correct model is one of these two, which has a greater probability of having generated the data?", that's a question I'd approach from a Bayesian viewpoint. If you mean something other than that, I think you'd need to be more precise about what you actually mean by 'more likely' (I presume it's not intended to be formally a reference to likelihood).

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. How can I approach it this way?

Answer (score 3):

More complicated model in this case is subset of other. You could easily test less restricted model versus more restricted one.

F-test and likelihood ratio test are based on this idea. You do not test then significance of parameter estimate of individual regressor.

Comment: Isn't the less complicated model a subset of the other one, not vice versa? Or am I misunderstanding? The way I'm seeing it is MC = {1, x, x^2}; LC = {1, x}, therefore LC $\subset$ MC.

Comment: Do you calculate the F-test using the folds from cross validation? Or what?

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron I am sorry, of course less complicated is subset of more complicated one. I can also test model structure via classical test statistics when using all observations.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, You can use cross-validation to opt for model complexity, which minimizes validation set error.
You should also analysis model diagnostic plots for both models.

Also, in R, you can use **anova()** function to compare nested models. There are many other functions to compare models based on different criteria.
Also, by visualizing data you can get a better understanding of the nature of relationship between the variables. Scatter plots should be the initial step before building regression model.